# php dynamic class inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, runtime, dynamicobject, dynamic-class-creation

I know I can generate a class at runtime by executing

```
$obj = (object)array('foo' => 'bar');+
```

this way I can use

```
echo $obj->foo; //bar
```

What if want to make $obj inherits from an existing class?

***What I wanna achive:***
I'm forking paris project on github (https://github.com/balanza/paris). It's an active record class. I wonder I need to declare a class for every object, even if it's empty:

```
class User extends Model{}
```

I guess I might use dynamic object to avoid this boring stuff.

Comment: So you want a totally obscure way to create an object which extends from the class because it's "boring" to define the class? Besides if your extension class is empty what's wrong with $obj = new Model();? Or is that "boring" too?

Comment: `(object)array()` does not "generate a class at runtime", it creates an **object**. That's an important difference.

Answer (score 2):

You could always do `eval('class User extends Model{}')` but is not a good idea. Really, you should just create the class in a file, then opcode caching will work properly, it can be version tracked, etc etc.

tl;dr: Define the model class, it is the Right Thing To Do™.

Answer (score 1):

If there is really no other way for you to do it, you can create a "dynamic" inheritance with my Dynherit class. It creates the inheritance you want but from files and only with classes you didnt already loaded.

Download v0.62 : http://optimisationphp.komrod.com/source/sha/test/dynamic_inheritance_01/dynherit_v0.62.zip

GitHub link : https://github.com/Komrod/Dynherit

Answer (score 0):

Strictly to your question, the only way I can see it possible is by using [Runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php), which let's you re-declare classes on the fly. Not sure how portable that solution is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Prototype design pattern to clone an object, then you can add everything you need in cloned one